# NoClassDefFoundError when running a class

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I am trying to run a class, but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 Exception in thread "main"
```

It happens, although the `main` method is in `MyClass` and I run directly this class.
Why is this class not found, although I launch the program from it?

Here is some code:

```
public class MyClass extends A implements B{
public MyClass() throws Exception {
//make some initializations
}
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
//do stuff with myClass
}
}
```

PS: I am using `Eclipse Indigo`.

**EDIT**
I have run the class in the Command Line twice:

```
D:\Eclipse JEE\Workspace2\Example\target\classes\com\example\main>java com.example.main.MyClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/main/MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.main.MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.example.main.MyClass.  Program will exit.

D:\Eclipse JEE\Workspace2\Example\target\classes\com\example\main>java GeoDAOImpl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClass(wrong name: com/example/main/MyClass)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: MyClass.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Are the class and it's default constructor `public` ?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes, it is `public`

Comment: Please show how you're trying to run the code, and a short but complete example of the code in question.

Comment: please have a look on how to resolve the issue http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: @JonSkeet The question has been updated.

Comment: @Dragos: You still haven't shown how you're running it. "I run directly this class" isn't very precise. What are A and B here? Is your class really not in a package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't really given us enough information to say for sure, but my guess is that either:

- You're not giving the right *fully-qualified* class name
- Your class isn't on the classpath

For an example of the first case, if your code looks like this:

```
package foo;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Then you should be running:

```
java foo.MyClass
```

EDIT: With the extra information provided, I suspect I know what's happened. I suspect the class was *created* not in a package, and a Run Configuration was created which just runs `MyClass`. It's now been moved into `com.example.main`, but without the Run Configuration being updated.

Go into the Run Configuration editor (click on the dropdown next to the "run" button, and select Run Configurations...) and find "MyClass", then check which class is going to be run, and edit it to put the right package name in.

Comment: I am using `Eclipse Indigo` as IDE, so I shouldn't be compiling it by myself. I made an update on the question.

Comment: @Dragos: I didn't ask how you were compiling it - I asked how you were trying to *run* it.

Comment: OK. The class is in the project `Example`, in the package `com.example.main`. I open the project, open the package and inside it, I make a right-click on the class `MyClass`. A menu appears. I select from that menu `Run As -> Java Application`. This is how I always run an application in Eclipse, so I don't see what the problem is. `A` is a public abstract class in the same `com.example.main` package and `B` is a public interface in `com.example.interface`.

Comment: @Dragos: Okay, so if it's in a package of `com.example.main` it shouldn't be trying to run `MyClass`, it should be trying to run `com.example.main.MyClass`. Editing...

Comment: Nope, the Run Configuration is fine. There truly appears `com.example.main.MyClass`. Do you have any other ideas I might try?

Comment: @Dragos: What happens if you run it *through that run configuration*? Do you *also* still have a `MyClass` that's not in a package, by any chance?

Comment: That's the only class with that name. There is no other in another package or not. I have tried runnig it through that configuration, but no change could be observed.

Comment: @Dragos: Have you tried running it from the command line, in the `bin` directory (or wherever you output your class files)?

Comment: Now I have tried that too. The same old problem: NoClassDef

Comment: @Dragos: So *is* there a `MyClass.class` file in `com/example/main` under your bin directory?

Comment: Yes, there is this class where it should be.

Comment: @Dragos: And you ran it as `java com.example.main.MyClass`? Can you try removing all the other dependencies (the class it extends, the interface it implements etc) and see if that helps?

Comment: I have removed them. Nothing changed. And yes, I have run it like you said.

Comment: @Dragos: What operating system are you on? Check the casing of all the file names and class names. Do you have a CLASSPATH environment variable set?

Comment: I am using Windows XP. The casing is right. I have a CLASSPATH environment variable set, pointing to somewhere in the Java dir. The `java` command works just fine, if that was what you were asking.

Comment: @Dragos: If you ran `java com.example.main.MyClass` then it shouldn't be saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClass` - because that's showing the packageless class. If you could give a short but complete program and a copy/paste of what happens when you run it from the console, that would really help to clarify things.

Comment: I have edited the question and added what I got in the command line.

Comment: @Dragos: You didn't follow my instructions. Yuo should be running from the `classes` directory, *not* `classes/com/example/main`. From the `classes` directory, run `java com.example.main.MyClass`. It's not clear why you've talked about `GeoDAOImpl`...

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems to work, the class is recognized now. `GeoDAOImpl` is a typing mistake. Sorry about that. Now what should I do to make Eclipse recognize the class?

Comment: @Dragos: I would double-check the run configuration - I *strongly* suspect that's the problem. You might want to try just removing all the existing run configurations, cleaning the project etc - then run it with the context menu again.

Comment: I have tried that, but with no actual results. I really don't have any idea about what might have caused the problem.

Comment: @Dragos: If you rename the class in Eclipse, then try to launch it again, what name does it report in the failure?

Comment: @JonSkeet I hate to break up the interactive debugging session, but could we (and by we, I mean you and Dragos) perhaps move this to chat? Thanks. =)

Comment: @Dragos I hate to break up the interactive debugging session, but could we (and by we, I mean you and Jon Skeet) perhaps move this to chat? Thanks. =)

Comment: @casperOne Thank you, Jon Skeet for your patience. I finally solved the problem by creating a new project and copying the packages by drag and drop. It seems to me that this was another Eclipse bug. You were the only one who provided helpful advice, so I am going to accept your answer. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to compile your source file if you haven't already done so. Assuming that your class `MyClass` is not in a package, and you are in the directory that contains the source file `MyClass.java`, compile it with:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

You should now have a file named `MyClass.class`.

Then, to run it, you need to make sure that the directory that contains the `MyClass.class` file is in the classpath. If you do not have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set, Java will by default look in the current directory, so you should be able to run it with:

```
java MyClass
```

If this doesn't work, you can explicitly put the current directory `.` in the classpath using the `-cp` option:

```
java -cp . MyClass
```

Comment: I am using `Eclipse Indigo` as IDE, so I shouldn't be compiling it by myself. I made an update on the question.